# What does ドロドロしてた mean in 生徒会はこんなにドロドロしてた

Tags: meaning

To provide some context, if not apparent, they are looking to take part in the school election and have just been shown all the other groups that they are competing with.

From what I can see there are a lot of uses for ドロドロ and I'm not quite sure how to understand it in this context.

> 雲母「このシートを見てみろ。我々の他に参戦している敵団体だ」
>
> 灯「えっと……うわ、多い……」
>
> 灯「放送委員会、神撫学園吹奏楽団、学園紳士淑女同盟、大世紀魔術研究部……委員会や部活だけじゃないんだー」
>
> 雲母「それに加えて、前生徒会長。再選を狙い出馬しているらしい」
>
> 歩武「うえぇ……俺達が無関心でいる間に、**生徒会はこんなにドロドロしてたのか**」

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://eikaiwa.dmm.com/uknow/questions/9071/) and [this](https://eikaiwa.dmm.com/uknow/questions/23020/), when ドロドロ refers to human relationships, it can be translated like:

- ugly (relationship)
- messy (relationship)
- toxic (relationship)
- like a soap opera

I think you can use "dirty", too.